# Problems with encoding in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, encoding

I have such a line of code which create a dynamic route.

```
<Link href={`/bundeslander/${urlName}`} ><div className=" text-blue-400">{state.name}</div></Link>
```

urlName is a variable which is created by getting data from API. In one case it is 'Thüringen'
And when I try to display params.name (name is dynamic segment) I see something like this Th%C3%BCringen.
Btw the link is generated normally.
[This is link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYM76.png)
Why it is happening this way.
Encoding is utf-8

I fixed it by replacing ü with u. But I would like to know by it is happening this way.
Thank you in advance. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is happening has to do with url encoding and the [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent?retiredLocale=de) method that is probably called by the `Link` component internally.

---

A suitable approach is using the [slugify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify) package to encode, clean and properly handle any dynamic slugs in your app. Here is an example component that you could use to achieve your goal:

```
import slugify from "slugify";
import { useMemo } from "react";
import Link, { type LinkProps } from "next/link";

interface SlugifyOptions {
  replacement?: string;
  remove?: RegExp;
  lower?: boolean;
  strict?: boolean;
  locale?: string;
  trim?: boolean;
}

interface Props {
  // the base part of the link e.g "/bundeslander"
  href: string;
  // the dynamic part of the url e.g "Thüringen"
  slug: string;
  // options for the link component
  linkOptions?: Omit<LinkProps, "href">;
  // options for the slugify function
  slugOptions?: SlugifyOptions;
}

export default function LinkWithSlug(props: Props): JSX.Element {
  const { href, slug, slugOptions, linkOptions } = props;

  const segment = useMemo(() => {
    return slugify(slug, slugOptions);
  }, [slug, slugOptions]);

  return <Link {...linkOptions} href={`${href}/${segment}`} />;
}
```

When configured correctly, the `slugify` method will replace any umlaute with their gramatical counterparts e.g "ü" with "ue" and so forth.

Of course you could also build your own replacer as this is completely unbiased. I just used this package in the past and know that it works well with the german language.